# Unable to add the caption in the tables for Latex

Tags: tables, captions

I have been trying to add the caption in the table and I also checked the documentation in the Overleaf for help but it does not work.
I used the following code.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
 \hline
 S. No. & Reagent & Powerplex® - 21\textsuperscript{\textregistered} & PowerPlex Y23\textsuperscript{\textregistered} \\ 
 \hline
 1 & Master Mix & 5 & 5 \\
 \hline
 2 & Primer Mixture & 5 & 2.5 \\
 \hline
 3 & Sample DNA & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 4 & Water & 14 & 14 \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total reaction Volume} & 25\mu L & 22.5\mu L \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Reaction volume for Powerplex\textsuperscript{\textregistered} - 21 and PowerPlex Y23\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\end{enumerate}
```

I even Tried to put the caption command in the top and in bottom both.

Comment: \caption should be used in a `table` environment

Comment: If you want to add a caption without using the `table` environment, you can use `\captionof{table}{...}` from the `caption` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using your code on overleaf it clearly gave the error:

> LaTeX Error: \caption outside figure or table.

So this should be a good place to start.

**\caption** should not be used inside **tabular**, it is always used inside **table**.
Here is the corrected version of your table:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| }
        \hline
        S. No. & Reagent & Powerplex\textsuperscript{\textregistered} - 21\textsuperscript{\textregistered} & PowerPlex Y23\textsuperscript{\textregistered} \\ 
        \hline
        1 & Master Mix & 5 & 5 \\
        \hline
        2 & Primer Mixture & 5 & 2.5 \\
        \hline
        3 & Sample DNA & 1 & 1 \\
        \hline
        4 & Water & 14 & 14 \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total reaction Volume} & 25$\mu$ L & 22.5$\mu$ L \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Reaction volume for Powerplex\textsuperscript{\textregistered} - 21 and PowerPlex Y23\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hey, @PulkitVerma Thank you for the help, it worked.